# How to read missing data when reading txt file in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS.

I want to read a txt file in SAS. The thing is the file has missing data in some lines.

For example the data is:

```
James Monroe        Monroe Hall         Virginia          58    4/28/1758   1816
John Quincy Adams   Braintree           Massachusetts     57    7/11/1767   1824    113,142 30.92%
Andrew Jackson      Waxhaws Region      South/North Carolina    61  3/15/1767   1828    642,806 55.93%
Martin Van Buren    Kinderhook          New York    54  12/5/1782   1836    763,291 50.79%
William Henry Harrison  Charles City County     Virginia    68  2/9/1773    1840    1,275,583   52.87%
```

The columns I want are 'FullName', 'City', 'State', 'Age', DOB', 'Year','Number' and 'Percentage'.

My code is:

```
infile 'C:\sasfiles\testfile.txt' missover dlm='09'x dsd
input FullName City State Age DOB Year Number PercVote;

Run;
```

But I get the error

> 9  CHAR  Rutherford B. Hayes.Delaware   ..Ohio..54.10/4/1822.1876.4,034,142.47.92% 73
>       ZONE  5776676676242246767046667676222004666003303323233330333303233323330332332
>       NUMR  2548526F2402E081953945C1712500099F89F9954910F4F18229187694C034C142947E925
>   FullName=. City=. State=. Age=. DOB=. Year=54 Number=. PercVote=1876 *ERROR*=1 *N*=19
>   NOTE: Invalid data for FullName in line 20 1-17.
>   NOTE: Invalid data for City in line 20 19-32.
>   NOTE: Invalid data for State in line 20 37-40.
>   NOTE: Invalid data for Number in line 20 46-55.
>   NOTE: Invalid data for PercVote in line 20 62-70.

Comment: That can't be all your code? Do you have informats for your date vars? Or strings?

Comment: @Reeza, I don't have informats.

Comment: Try using them. And change MISSOVER to TRUNCOVER.

Comment: @Reeza. I don't know whether I have to add `w.d` in the column. For example, `input FullName $23.`. If I do it in this way, it may bring some of substring of the next column to it. And for the original input text file, should I pre-process it? Otherwise, how can I align the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide data in a format that can by properly parsed.

When using delimited data then use adjacent delimiters to indicate there is a value missing.  It is best to define the variables before you use them. If you define them in order then your input statement can be very simple.

```
data want ;
   infile cards dsd dlm='|' firstobs=2 truncover ;
   length name $13 city $11 state $15 age 8 dob 8 yod 8 ;
   input name -- yod ;
   informat dob mmddyy10.;
   format dob yymmdd10.;
cards;
----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0
James Monroe|Monroe Hall|Virginia||4/28/1758|1816
John Quincy Adams|Braintree|Massachusetts|57|7/11/1767|1824 
;
```

Or force the data into columns and use column input.

```
data want ;
   infile cards firstobs=2 truncover ;
   input name $ 1-13 city $ 19-29 state $ 31-45 age 47-48 @50 dob mmddyy10. yod 61-64;
   format dob yymmdd10.;
cards;
----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0----+----0
James Monroe      Monroe Hall Virginia            4/28/1758 1816
John Quincy Adams Braintree   Massachusetts   57  7/11/1767 1824 
;
```

Comment: If you click edit on the question, you can copy and paste the original data lines, which are tab-delimited. Blockquoted tabs are displayed as spaces on this site.

Comment: Pipe is much better for posting examples since you can see it.

Comment: I am not sure should I set `Dob` as numeric format? Because I don't know whether `yymmdd10.` can do math calculation? The length of it is great than 8.

Comment: SAS uses 8 byte floating point to store all numbers, So 8 is the right length for a numeric variable. If you are storing integers you could use a smaller value and SAS will truncate the value when it stores. It is only worth it if you are working with really large data and need to save disk space. The format you use to display a date does not change the value stored.  I prefer using YMD to display dates because MDY or DMY values can easily be confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data want;
infile cards dlm='09'x missover;
input (FullName City State) (:$32.) Age :8. DOB :mmddyy9. Year :4. Number :comma8. PercVote :percent8.;
format DOB mmddyy10. number comma16.  percvote percent6.2;
cards;
James Monroe        Monroe Hall         Virginia          58    4/28/1758   1816
John Quincy Adams   Braintree           Massachusetts     57    7/11/1767   1824    113,142 30.92%
Andrew Jackson      Waxhaws Region      South/North Carolina    61  3/15/1767   1828    642,806 55.93%
Martin Van Buren    Kinderhook          New York    54  12/5/1782   1836    763,291 50.79%
William Henry Harrison  Charles City County     Virginia    68  2/9/1773    1840    1,275,583   52.87%
;
run;
```